# WPF Web (xbap) using WCF Service throws System.Net.webPermission exception

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, xbap, partial-trust

I have an xbap application running with partial trust on my local machine's IIS 7.5. I published the WCF service to the same directery as the xbap.

After jumping through some hoops I could get it working through Visual Studio for debugging perposes, but I can't seem to get it to work on an IIS server after it's published.

I'm running on .Net 4.0

Contents of the error:
"Request for the permission of type System.Net.webPermission, System
Version=4.0.0.0, culture neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c56l934e089 failed."

Update:

So I started over, making a new Wcf service, new Xbap and a new site to deploy to. After verifying every step of the way, I got it to work. So I started to integrate my previous apps, one-by-one, over to the new site to discover what was the problem. I narrowed it down to my original Wcf service, but after making it identical to the working one, it still has the WebPermission error.

So, I still don't know what was causing the problem, other than redoing it fixed it.

Comment: Anyone found any solution of this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, looking through the web.config file I noticed that I had commented out the following line:

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

I uncommented it and no more error.

Comment: Could you please explain about same.